# How to display text inside a moving object in java/processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm using the Processing IDE and I found out how to display static text but not one that displays inside and moves with the moving disk. Any help?

```
int xdirection = 1;  // Left or Right
int ydirection = 1;  // Top to Bottom
int value = 0;
Disk disk1;
Disk disk2;
Disk disk3;
Disk disk4;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  cursor(CROSS);
  noStroke();
  disk1 = new Disk(color(255, 0, 0), 10, 100, 2, 6);
  disk2 = new Disk(color(0, 0, 255), 10, 100, 1, 5);
  disk3 = new Disk(color(0, 255, 0), 10, 100, 3, 4);
  disk4 = new Disk(color(0, 255, 255), 10, 100, 4, 7);
  frameRate(60);
}
void mousePressed() {
  if (disk1.isOver() == true) {
    value += 25;
  }
  if (disk2.isOver() == true) {
    value += 50;
  }
  if (disk3.isOver() == true) {
    value += 75;
  }
  if (disk4.isOver() == true) {
    value += 100;
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(130, 140, 255);
  stroke(175);
  fill(0);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text("Score: " + value, width/2, 60);
  disk1.bounce();
  disk1.display();
  disk2.bounce();
  disk2.display();
  disk3.bounce();
  disk3.display();
  disk4.bounce();
  disk4.display();
}

class Disk {
  color c;
  float xpos;
  float ypos;
  float xspeed;
  float yspeed;

  Disk(color tempC, float tempXpos, float tempYpos, float tempXspeed, float tempYspeed) {
    c = tempC;
    xspeed = tempXspeed;
    yspeed = tempYspeed;
    if (xpos > width-200 || xpos < 0) {
      xdirection *= -1;
    }
    if (ypos > height-200 || ypos < 0) {
      ydirection *= -1;
    }
  }

  void display() {
    stroke(0);
    fill(c);
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    ellipse(xpos, ypos, 20, 20);
  }

  boolean isOver() {
    // Is mouse position over the circle i.e. dist < radius
    if (dist(xpos, ypos, mouseX, mouseY) < 10)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  void bounce() {
    xpos = xpos + xspeed;
    xpos = xpos + ( xspeed * xdirection );
    ypos = ypos + ( yspeed * ydirection );
    if (xpos > width - 20) {
      xspeed = xspeed * -1;
    }
    if (xpos < 0) {
      xspeed = xspeed * -1;
    }
    if (ypos > height - 20) {
      yspeed = yspeed * -1;
    }
    if (ypos < 0) {
      yspeed = yspeed * -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Updated post to show code. I'm also trying to figure out how to make the disks larger using `scale()` but haven't been able to find out how to do so. This is also my first time posting on stack overflow so if there is anything I can do better, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Please show some code. Also: the text's coordinates have to follow the object you want it to follow, so you'll have to calculate them accordingly. If it confuses you I may be able to help once I can see with what you're working.

Comment: @laancelot Post is updated

Comment: @laancelot This is based on a template that was given to me. I'm still in the learning process so if you could just give some guidance on how to proceed that would be great. This is for a homework so I'd rather not be given the answer directly

Comment: Kevin was first and his answer is fine, but if somehow you're still stumped you can still message me (link with the @ or I won't know).

Answer (score 0):

The `Disk` class encapsulates the state of a single `Disk` instance. It contains code for checking mouse clicks and for bouncing. It also contains code for drawing a disk.

That code happens in the `display()` function. Read through that function to understand what it's doing, and try changing it to see what happens.

Specifically, this line of code draws a circle at the disk's location:

```
ellipse(xpos, ypos, 20, 20);
```

Try changing that do draw a rectangle at the disk's location. Then try changing it to draw some text at the disk's location.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'll take another shot at it